# Setting up Nutch with Solr on Centos

Tags: nutch

I'm attempting to setup Apache Nutch and Apache Solr so our site can have internal site search. I have followed so my guides and while they are very useful, they lack what to do if an error occurs and most seem outdated at this point.

I'm using JDK 131, Nutch 2.3.1, and Solr 6.5.1

This the sequence of my actions from the none root user

```
sudo wget [java url] to /opt
sudo tar xvf java.tar.gz
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/
export JAVA_JRE=/opt/java/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/java/bin:/opt/java/jre/bin
cd solr6.5.1/
sudo start runtime -e cloud -noprompt

sudo wget [solr url] to /root
sudo tar xvf solr.tar.gz


sudo wget [nutch url] to /opt
sudo tar xvf nutch.tar.gz
cd /opt/apache-nutch-2.3.1
sudo vi nutch-site.xml
```

add:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>http.agent.name</name>
  <value>nutch-solr-integration</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>generate.max.per.host</name>
  <value>100</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika|metatags)|index-(basic|anchor|metadata)|query-(basic|site|url)|response-(json|xml)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|indexer-solr|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
  <description> At the very least, I needed to add the parse-html, urlfilter-regex, and the indexer-solr.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>storage.data.store.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.gora.sql.store.SqlStore</value>
  <description>The Gora DataStore class for storing and retrieving data.</description>
</property>
</configuration>

cd /opt/apache-nutch-2.3.1
mkdir urls
cd urls
sudo vi seed.txt
  add [our site url]
[ESC]
:w
:q
cd ../conf
sudo vi regex-urlfilter.xml
add:
+^http://([a-zA-Z0-9]*\.)*[domain of our site].com/
[ESC]
:w
:q
cd ..
sudo ant runtime
sudo -E runtime/local/bin/nutch inject urls -crawlId 3
```

Then I get this:

```
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls
InjectorJob: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.gora.sql.store.SqlStore
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.getDataStoreClass(StorageUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:218)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)
```

My questions are how why am I getting this error and how do I resolve it. I saw in a lot of places to modify the schema.xml the solr directory but there is no schema.xml file in the solr directory anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using sql-store as Nutch back-end, did you edit `ivy/ivy.xml` and uncomment this line?

```
<dependency org="org.apache.gora" name="gora-sql" rev="0.1.1-incubating" conf="*->default" />
```

If not, uncomment this line and clean & build again. If it's still not working, let me know your complete approach or the tutorial you followed.

**Edit**

As you said, you are using hbase as store, your nutch-site.xml property is supposed to be this -

```
<property>
    <name>storage.data.store.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore</value>
</property>
```

Please follow the link you mentioned carefully.

Comment: That resolved the with injecting the url. Now I'm having an error with the generate code 
**sudo -E runtime/local/bin/nutch generate -topN 10**
GeneratorJob: starting at 2017-05-30 11:33:08
GeneratorJob: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
GeneratorJob: starting
GeneratorJob: filtering: true
GeneratorJob: normalizing: true
GeneratorJob: topN: 10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration

Comment: are you using hbase as data store?

Comment: I believe so. I installed it and followed these instructions [link](https://anil.io/blog/apache/nutch/apache-nutch-2-3-hbase-0-94-14-and-solr-5-2-1-tutorial/)

Comment: yes, I've also followed this link and it worked perfectly. So as you're using hbase as store, you should re-comment again the above line I mentioned in `ivy/ivy.xml`. And make sure you've followed all the steps strictly mentioned in the blog. And try to execute `ant clean` and `ant runtime` and let me know what happened.

Comment: Sorry, I have been away unexpectedly. I have gone back followed all the steps and it seemed like everything started working. Now when I do bin/nutch inject urls it seems to hang. I have wait 1 hour and it still hasn't finished.